# Eigenvalues without the axiom of choice

Tags: eigenvalues, axiom-of-choice, vector-spaces

Without the Axiom of Choice (AC), we can find models of ZF set theory in which some vector spaces have no base, and also models in which some vector spaces have bases of different cardinalities.

The question I am thinking of might be totally absurd.

Could we find a matrix $M$ over some field $\ell$ in some model of ZF set theory without AC which has multiple, different sets of eigenvalues ? (So that some eigenvalue would occur in one set, but not in the other.)

Comment: What does this mean? Normally we say $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if there is some (nonzero) vector $v$ such that $Mv = \lambda v$. There cannot be "different sets" of $\lambda$ for this definition...

Comment: I don’t understand the downvoting; OP prefaced that the question might be absurd. If there are bases of different cardinality in different models of ZF, then it is not unreasonable to ask whether the set of eigenvalues could be different in different models of ZF. If you change “set” to “multiset”, and consider the identity operator, they become the same question!

Comment: @Kevin: Presumably the matrix is not finite (which would probably benefit an explicit mention); but even though, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then there is some $v$ such that $Mv=\lambda v$. Vectors and operators are not their representation via some basis. So how would the existence of a basis, lack thereof, or existence of different sizes of bases affect that $Mv=\lambda v$? I know that AC is interesting, and that a lot of things can be paradoxical, but before asking an absurd question, one might want to spend more time [than usual] thinking about it.

Comment: @KevinVentullo: Your question seems reasonable.  But as written, the original question seems to be asking whether there exists a *single* model in which there are two different sets, both of which are the set of eigenvalues of $M$.  That seems to be a trivial "no".

Comment: Fair enough. But as mathematicians I think we should default to the most generous interpretation of a question, if for no other reason than to encourage questions. Questions are our lifeblood! If that makes our answer purely misinterpretation, then so be it; it may still be interesting. With that in mind, and with THC’s permission, let us reinterpret the question as follows: is there a linear operator, a value lambda, and distinct models of ZF in which the operator has lambda as an eigenvalue in one model and not the other?

Comment: @KevinVentullo I'm not sure that formulation is interesting either.  Here is a simple example obeying the properties you asked for: take the vector space to be just the one-dimensional reals, let $T = 1_{Con(ZF)}$ be the operator defined to be the identity if $Con(ZF)$ is true and zero otherwise, and let $\lambda = 0$.  (Part of the problem is one needs to specify what it even means to specify an object, such as a linear operator, that somehow exists across several models.)